# ASP.net Membership Validation is not working in other system

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

I have created User,Roles and assign Roles to User through the functions provided by Membership functions("CreateUserRole","CreateMembershipUser" and "AssignUserToRole") in the aspnet database.The User,Roles are created successfully.I am able to login too in my system.

Same credentials I need to be configured in other machines too.So inserted same User/Password/Salt Password through scripts in all the membership tables.It is not working in other machines.Though the data is successfully inserted in other machines in the start up of the project.The function "ValidateUserCredentials" is giving error in other machines.Is there any setting to create password and Salt password while generating the first time?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **ASP.Net Membership Provider**, you need to check the following -

1. Both web.config files are same (except connection string).
2. **ApplicationName** is same in both Databases as well as both web.config files.
3. **Password Format** is **Hashed**, set **hashAlgorithmType** explicitly in **membership** tag inside both web.config, because different membership providers use different hashed algorithms.

For example,

```
<membership defaultProvider="..." hashAlgorithmType="SHA1">
```

4. Rule of thumb is you want to include same **machine key** in both web.config even if **Password Format** is **Hashed**. *(If Password Format is **Encrypted**, machine key is mandatory and same machine key must be included in both web.config files)*

Comment: Do we need this machine key configuration when we work with same user credentials in different servers?

Comment: **Machine Key** is not necessary *(although it is recommended)* if **Password Format** is stored as **Hashed**.